# Implementing Competing Consumers Pattern using Camel

Tags: apache-camel

How can I keep my competing consumers completely dynamic?
 Camel implementation is asking for concurrentConsumers value. But let's say if a new consumer boots up and start consuming the sender messages. How am I going to keep a count of concurrent consumers then?

Comment: After reading several related questions you have posted here, it might help to clearly define your usecase.  What you ask is possible but would take some effort so maybe stating what it is you are trying to accomplish would help you get to the solution much quicker. :)

Comment: Also, concurrentConsumers is just the minimum number of consumers created at initialization.  Setting the maxConcurrentConsumers to equal that of concurrentConsumers will give you a constant.  That isn't "dynamic" though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume you are talking about JMS consumers...

If so, you can set the concurrentConsumers & maxConcurrentConsumers to allow the number of active consumer threads to grow/shrink based on demand.  something like this will setup a route explicitly...

```
from("activemq:queue:input?concurrentConsumers=1&maxConcurrentConsumers=5")
.to("log:+++consumed+++");
```

that said, if you have other routes (or non-route consumers like Spring JMSTemplates, etc) that start consuming from the same resource (input queue), then the number of total consumers can go much higher...

you can always view the total number of active consumers in the AMQ web console or via JMX

Comment: Although If you want the number if consumers to shrink down when the load is not high you have to set the `maxMessagesPerTask` property too. As said [in the docs here](http://camel.apache.org/jms.html):

The `maxMessagesPerTask` option MUST be set to an integer greater than 0 for threads to scale down. Otherwise, the number of threads will stay at maxConcurrentConsumers until shutdown.